# Do not show the middle activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In my project, I'm using 3 activity classes. It is processed sequentially as

```
A > B > C
```

But I only need to show the process as `A > C`. I do not need to open another window for B activity. I just need to show A window to C window. How can I avoid B activity's window in my android application?

Comment: It looks like you need to do B's logic in C and remove B altogether. You never need an activity in android if it has no View.

Comment: you mean you want to close B activity when you reach C actvity?

Comment: I need B activity (no need to close). But it opens another blank window for activity B. I need to avoid that

Comment: Why exactly do you need it if it opens a blank window?

Comment: When I back to activity A again. I have to press back button for this blank window too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you

1. Give your intermediate Activity B the theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"` (configured in AndroidManifest.xml)
2. Ensure that Activity B's `onCreate()` does both `startActivity(intentToStartC)` and  `finish()`

then your Activity B will immediately delegate to C without ever showing any UI.

Comment: It give an error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'theme' with value 'Theme.NoDisplay')

Comment: Sorry, I initially mistyped the theme. Should be correct now.

Also: Is your intermediate Activity B `finish()`ing itself during `onCreate()`? It should but the fact that you mention that B is still showing on the back stack suggests that it currently doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, Activity B is not finish. Then it shows black window. How can I finish() the activity B.

Comment: By putting the line:

`finish();`

inside your Activity B's `onCreate()` method. Each Activity has a `finish()` method which terminates the Activity. Since you want Activity B to terminate immediately after `startActivity()` which you're presumably doing during `onCreate()`, you should also call `finish()` from that same method.